# Какой id вернёт lastInsertId() из PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Использую PHP и MySQL. Насколько я понял, `lastInsertId()` возвращает id последнего добавленного элемента.

Но я не понимаю, это будет id последнего, добавленного мною элемента, или это id вообще последнего добавленного элемента (возможно другим пользователем)? И как указать этому методу нужную таблицу.

То есть, если я сделаю INSERT в таблицу, а потом вызову `lastInsertId()`, то гарантируется, что получу id именно этого INSERT? Или если другой пользователь успеет сделать свой INSERT в промежутке, то я могу получить его id вместо своего?

Comment: У другого пользователя будет другой коннект к SQL серверу.

lastInsertId() вернёт последний ID из текущей сессии SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вернуть id последнего добавленного тобою элемента - **единственное** предназначение этой функции. Если бы она этого не делала, то попросту не имела бы смысла.

Для mysql эта функция возвращает результат функции [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), про которую сказано, что значение возвращается для текущего соединения. Поэтому бояться этой функции не надо.

Никакую "таблицу" при работе с mysql указывать не надо.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Из документации:

```
PDO::lastInsertId — Возвращает ID последней вставленной строки или последовательное значение
PDO::lastInsertId ([ string $name = NULL ] )
Если 'name' не задан, PDO::lastInsertId() вернет строку представляющую ID последней добавленной в базу записи.
Если 'name' задан, PDO::lastInsertId() вернет строку представляющую последнее значение, полученное от этого объекта.
Если PDO драйвер не поддерживает эту возможность, PDO::lastInsertId() запишет IM001 в SQLSTATE.
```

Таким образом получается, что если Вы хотите гарантировано получить `id` добавленной Вами записи, укажите имя объекта (таблицу). В этом случе Вы получите созданный именно Вами `id`.

Comment: Рекомендую удалить этот ответ и впредь не писать на темы, в которых ничего не понимаешь.

Comment: я всего лишь скопировал документацию

Comment: Однако, признаю, что Ваш ответ более лаконичен и отметает всякие сомнения... а посему, пометим его как полезный. Спасибо за науку. В конце концов мы все сюда ради науки и ходим... :)